# How to fix 'list' object has no attribute 'get' (AttributeError) in Python/Django

Tags: python, django

I want to use form to create new objects in database but i can't run this view. Where do i need to make some changes ?

I was trying to delete "def get" function but it was only white screen, like blank page after that.

```
class AddOrderForm(forms.Form):
    airport         =   forms.ChoiceField(choices=AIRPORT_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(AIRPORT_CHOICES))
    direction       =   forms.ChoiceField(choices=DIRECTION_CHOICES)
    adress          =   forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Turmstraße 57"}))
    client          =   forms.CharField()
    telephone       =   forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "+49XXXXXXXXX"}))
    flight_number   =   forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "LL 0000"}))
    plane           =   forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])
    pick_up         =   forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])
    gate            =   forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "G or A11"}))
    driver          =   forms.ChoiceField(choices=DRIVER_CHOICES)

class AddOrderView(View):

def get(self, request):
    form = AddOrderForm()
    return render(request, 'orders/add_order.html', {'form': form})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = AddOrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        order = Order.objects.create(airport=form.cleaned_data['airport'],
                                     direction=form.cleaned_data['direction'],
                                     adress=form.cleaned_data['adress'],
                                     client=form.cleaned_data['client'],
                                     telephone=form.cleaned_data['telephone'],
                                     flight_number=form.cleaned_data['flight_number'],
                                     plane=form.cleaned_data['plane'],
                                     pick_up=form.cleaned_data['pick_up'],
                                     gate=form.cleaned_data['gate'],
                                     driver=form.cleaned_data['driver'])
        return redirect(f'order/{order.id}')
    return render(request, 'orders/add_order.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the problem with this code?

Comment: OK you've mentioned an error. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/21WT26J

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `RadioSelect` should be `attrs`, but you are passing choices.

The form field will take care of passing choices to the widget, so the easiest solution is to change your code to `widget=forms.RadioSelect`.

```
airport = forms.ChoiceField(choices=AIRPORT_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your def get() function return add_order.html page that's why when you are trying to delete function then Html page is not found to show any data ultimately it shows blank.